# Find the timestamp of last metrics value change

Tags: timestamp, prometheus, metrics, promql

I'm trying to determine when a specific metric was last checked or updated for a project. I'm attempting to achieve this by making an API call, but I'm having trouble getting the correct date and time value.

The API call I'm using looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=metric_name&start=start_time&end=end_time&step=1m
```

I specify the start_time and end_time values, but even if I set the step value to 1m, I'm not getting the accurate result.

So, my question is, how can I accurately obtain the timestamp of the last update? How should I structure the API call to achieve this?

I attempted to retrieve the last updated timestamp for a specific metric by making an API call using the following query:

http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=metric_name&start=start_time&end=end_time&step=1m

I provided values for start_time and end_time to narrow down the time range, and I set the step parameter to 1m to capture data at one-minute intervals.

I expected the API call to return the accurate timestamp of the metric's last update within the specified time range. However, the results I received were not as expected. The timestamps returned by the API call did not seem to correspond to the actual last update time of the metric.

In summary, I tried to use the API call to find the last updated timestamp of a metric, but the obtained timestamps were not accurate based on my expectations.

Comment: `api/v1/query_range` returns all metric values within specified time range. If you need to get only timestamp of last change/appearance  you need to pass query for that.

Comment: Please clarify, do you have a continuous metric, that rarely changes and you want timestamp of last change, or do you have metric that is rarely present, and you want timestamp of its last presence?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My metric is continuously changing, and yes, I'm looking to retrieve the timestamp of the last change. I'm using the api/v1/query_range endpoint to fetch the metric values. After obtaining these values, I'm planning to find the maximum value in a separate code block and then display it.

Comment: But, if it's possible to find the maximum value during query time, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with combination of functions `changes`, `timestamp` and `last_over_time`.

Query

```
last_over_time(
 timestamp(
  changes(
   prometheus_http_requests_total{}[1m]
  ) > 0
 )[1d:]
)
```

will return timestamp of last change in metric `prometheus_http_requests_total` if it happened within last day.

Adjust query for your metric and possible maximum period of changes absence.

Your final URL will look like this:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?time=end_time&query=last_over_time%28timestamp%28changes%metric_name%7B%7D%5B1m%5D%29%3E0%29%5B1d%3A%5D%29
```

Comment: It looks like true but Its not working with my metrics,what could be the reason?

Comment: It's hard to tell without details. Take this query and debug it (go to webui, insert inner-most part, look what returned and if it is according to your expectations, and so on).

Comment: The last value displayed in the chart and the largest timestamp by timestamp(metric_name) are not showing correctly because they are different values. What could be the reason for this? Why are they both different?

Comment: @beyz, they almost never the same: they will be equal only if value changed within last minute.

Comment: Actually, that's my problem. So as you say, unless I'm checking the graph and the timestamp data at the same time, can't it be the same at all? What is the reason?

Comment: @beyz, Because larges timestamp is basically time of last scrape. Na the one returned by my query is a time of last value change.

Comment: I want to learn exact the last timestamp time, how can I find?And, Lets say, the graph shows the last timestamp:20:09 but your query or the other queries show 20:43. I couldn't understand. If your query show the last change , Shouldn't it show an earlier time?

Comment: @beyz, This shouldn't be the case. [Consider this demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=last_over_time(%0A%20timestamp(%0A%20%20changes(%0A%20%20%20prometheus_http_requests_total%7Bhandler%3D%22%2Fstatus%22%7D%5B1m%5D%0A%20%20)%20%3E%200%0A%20)%5B1d%3A%5D%0A)&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=timestamp(prometheus_http_requests_total%7Bhandler%3D%22%2Fstatus%22%7D)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h)

Comment: Okay,but how can I find the time of last scrape? Is it possible?